# Update ODBC Query in Excel from PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel

We have several spreadsheets connecting using ODBC to a MS SQL database. However when working remotely, we don't have that luxury of allowing the spreadsheet to talk to a database, and on top of this, we ideally want to apply a filter to the ODBC query to the SQL Database.

The PHP App does however have access to the database.

Using PHP, can we open the spreadsheet and refresh the data before returning the spreadsheet back to the user for download?

Comment: It's not clear (to me..) what you're asking exactly. Are you asking if `phpexcel` has the ability to read queries from Excel files? Or if PHP can connect to MS SQL? or something else..?

Comment: We have an Excel Spreadsheet that connects to SQL using ODBC. But because the database isn't available remotely, we somehow need to open the spreadsheet in PHP using OLE or something to dynamically refresh/filter the data before allowing the user to download the spreadsheet with the previously refreshed data.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but I'm not sure I understand what the question is...